# Mockito test when(repository.findById()).thenReturn(object with custom attributes)

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, repository

So I was writing a couple of unit tests, some of them were made for testing missing attributes of `Document`. When using of `when(repository.findOne(id)).thenReturn(DOCUMENT_WITHOUT_SOMETHING)`, those DOCUMENT_WITHOUT_SOMETHING were final objects with predefined attributes, depending on test cases.

Let's say, there could be a document without name, so when loading `document` by `id` the method was returning `null` with some log message. So I created a **class of test data** `DocumentServiceTestData`, where those necessary objects and attributes were declared. Is it a good approach or you suggest something more clear, without need of making new class?

I will try to write a simplified code of what I did.

**Document**

```java
public class Document {

    private String name;
    private String applicant;
    private String sign;
    private boolean signed;

    public boolean isSigned() {return signed;}
    public String getApplicant() {return applicant;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public String getSign() {return sign;}
    public void setSigned(boolean signed) {this.signed = signed;}
    public void setApplicant(String applicant) {this.applicant = applicant;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public void setSign(String sign) {this.sign = sign;}
}
```

**DocumentService**

```java
@Service
public class DocumentService {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DocumentService.class);
    private DocumentRepository documentRepository;

    public Document loadDocument(Long docId) {
        Document document = documentRepository.findByIdOrFail(docId);

        if(document.getName() == null) {
            LOG.info("There is no name for document, returning null");
            return null;
        }

        if(document.getSign() == null) {
            LOG.info("The document is not signed, returning null");
            return null;
        }

        return document;
    }
}
```

**DocumentServiceTestData**

```java
public class DocumentServiceTestData {

    public static final Long DOC_ID = 1L;
    public static final String APPLICANT = "Applicant";
    public static final String DOC_NAME = "Document";
    public static final String SIGN = "Sign";

    public static final Document DOCUMENT_WITHOUT_NAME;
    public static final Document DOCUMENT_WITHOUT_SIGN;

    static {
        DOCUMENT_WITHOUT_NAME = makeDocument(null, APPLICANT, SIGN, true);
        DOCUMENT_WITHOUT_SIGN = makeDocument(DOC_NAME, APPLICANT, null, false);
    }

    private static Document makeDocument(String name, String applicant, String sign, boolean signed) {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.setName(name);
        document.setApplicant(applicant);
        document.setSign(sign);
        document.setSigned(signed);

        return document;
    }
}
```

**DocumentServiceTest**

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@Category(MockTest.class)
public class DocumentServiceUnitTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private DocumentService service;
    @Mock
    private DocumentRepository documentRepository;

    @Test
    public void testLoadDocument_notSigned(){
        when(documentRepository.findByIdOrFail(DOC_ID)).thenReturn(DOCUMENT_WITHOUT_SIGN);

        Document document = service.loadDocument(DOC_ID);

        Assert.assertNull(document);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoadDocument_notNamed(){
        when(documentRepository.findByIdOrFail(DOC_ID)).thenReturn(DOCUMENT_WITHOUT_NAME);

        Document document = service.loadDocument(DOC_ID);

        Assert.assertNull(document);
    }
}
```

**To sum up, I would like to know - if there is another way to test those cases, when I need to return specified objects while calling `repository.findById(id)`.**

**PS:** keep in mind that this is very simplified, those tests I've made were much more complex. If there is any information missing please let me know, I will try to clarify things. Thanks

Comment: 1. Returning specific objects driving your code-under-test to take a specific path is totally ok. 2. What raises my eyebrow is the implementation of the service - you return null even if the (presumably invalid) object exists in the db.  This gives the caller little opportunity to know what the problem is and react to that.

Comment: 1. Thanks for clarification. 
2. As I said, the code is simplified and I didn't want to waste space with our 200-lines long service. I've just made it as an example.